# Lower case in Table caption

Tags: tables, captions

I want to write `$N_{\textrm{act}}$` in Table Caption. However, I get `act` as small caps `ACT`. I want `act` as lowercase in text `$N_{\textrm{act}}$`.

Comment: It's always best if you add a complete example. Presumably you have something that sets the caption font to small caps (e.g. `\usepackage[font=sc]{caption}`). Try with  `\mathrm` instead of `\textrm`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks. It works fine with `\mathrm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you have something that sets the caption font to small caps (e.g. `\usepackage[font=sc]{caption}`), and `\textrm` uses the current font shape (I suppose, without knowing exactly what happens 'under the hood'). Try with  `\mathrm` instead of `\textrm`, which uses the math roman font instead of the text roman font. Or you could use `\textrm{\normalfont act}`.

Answer (score 0):

`textrm` chooses the  `roman family`, not the shape. What you have in mind is `upshape`. So you could use the `caption`package and have `captionsetup{font=up}`in your preamble. You also can write, e.g. `captionsetup{labelfont={up,bf}, textfont=i}` if you want different settings for the label and the caption text. It may be set on a float type basis.

You may check the whole setting for your captions with the `\showcaptionsetup{table}` (cf. § 3.2 of the documentation).